# Accessing subclass methods by referencing superclass

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass called "Items" and a sub class called "PickUpHealth1". I create an array of Items similar to this code:

```
ArrayList<Items> itemsArray = new ArrayList<Items>();
Items h1 = new PickUpHealth1(x,y);
itemsArray.add(h1);
```

The subclass has it's own methods. I go through the array itemsArray and when a certain event occurs I want to initiate methods in the subclass PickUpHealth1. I know that the superclass doesn't know about the methods in the subclass but I don't want to create a separate array for each subclass if possible. Is there anyway I can reference the methods in the subclass through itemsArray? Since h1 is initialized as an object of PickUpHealth1 I would think there should be a way to do this, but I can't figure it out. Is there a way? Or am I going about it all wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Create an interface which `Item` implements, then code against that interface: all derived classes must also support the methods in the interface, either by implementing them or using a base class' implementation. If you have a situation where not all derived classes can share the same interface, you should probably use different lists for different items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `PickUpHealth1 extends Item` and you have a `List<Item> items`

As you've noted `Item`s can only do `Item` things, so you can't go trying to use `PickUpHealth1` methods when you are accessing it as an `Item` through the items list.

If `Item`s don't have anything in common then don't extend from it.

If they are all "useable" then give them a common method.

For example:

```
abstract class Item {
    public abstract void useItem();
}

class PickUpHealth extends Item  {
    private int healAmount;
    public PickUpHealth(int healAmount) {
        this.healAmount = healAmount;
    }

    @Override
    public void useItem() {
        player.addHealth(healAmount);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(new PickUpHealth(10));
    Item item = items.get(0);
    item.useItem();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The subclasses of Items have a lot in common, but they need to be able to do their own thing as well. I ended up creating a String called "type" in Items. I check "type" to see which subclass it should reference then I run the method(s) in that subclass accordingly. Probably not the best solution but it does keep me form having to have multiple arrays for each subclass. There will probably end up being a lot of subclasses and I wanted to work with just one array.

Comment: @Sark They can do their own thing with the mentioned `useItem()` method (as an example). Every subclass can implement its own way how the item is being used.

Comment: Oh I get it. You created a method "useItem" in the superclass which can be called and then override it in the subclass so it can do it's own thing. Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. If this answered your question then please accept it as the answer.